# $ x+A^c=(x+A)^c $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n $ and $x \in\mathbb{R}^n $.

I need to prove this $ x+A^c=(x+A)^c$,but I don't see how. 
This what I have done so far:

If $y \in x+A^c $, then $( y=x) \lor (y \in A^c)$, which means $ (y =x) \lor ( y \notin A)$

And on the other side is
If $y \in (x+A)^c $, then $( y\neq x) \land (y \in A^c)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement "If $y \in x+A^c$, then $(y=x) \vee (y \in A^c)$" is false. To see this, take $x=5$ and $A^c=[1,2]$.

As for a proof:

$$y \in (x+A)^c \Leftrightarrow y \notin x+A \Leftrightarrow y-x \notin A \Leftrightarrow y-x \in A^c \Leftrightarrow y \in x+A^c. $$

Comment: I might have been confused but what's the definition of x+A you are using? Because I was using the definition of adding that point to A (like sort of a union).

Comment: @Deni I was thinking that $x+A$ means translating $A$ by $x$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much both of you! Now it is all clear, I could complete all of the problems  :)